Purpose of this valve next to my main water supply line
Take a look at the picture of my main shut off valve, my question is, why there is a pressure relief valve next to it? And what is that pipe which goes down in the floor for?
Although I know that it pressure relief valve, if you can explain how it works and purpose of it, it would be better. I don't have food knowledge of plumbing.
I am in 2nd floor condominium, building is more than 37 years old.
My water heater has its own pressure relief valve in case someone ask that question.


The pipe going through the floor, connects to your drain/sewer line to drain water from a tank leak and a pressure relief valve opening up.
I imagine there is/are main pressure regulating valves in the building, so that pressure relief is probably a back up safety, so extreme water pressure regulator failure does not burst/cause leaks in your pipes.
Pressure relief valves open and drain water.  That water needs to go somewhere.
